How to find generator in ellipse curve?
I have read topic "How to find generator in a finite group?what is generator?" where is fast method checking if element is finite field generator: need factorize p-1 and use powers.
Sage code:
def is_generator(a, p, F):
    for fpair in F:
        f = fpair[0]
        b = power_mod(a, (p-1)//f,p)
        if b == 1:
            return False
    return True

bits = 256
p = random_prime(2^bits - 1, True, 2^(bits-1))
F = factor(p-1)
print("is factorized")
for  a in range(2, p):
    if is_generator(a,p,F):
        print(p, a)
        break

It is very fast method, main waiting time is for factoring.
I wonder, what is a method checking point on Ellipse is generator?
For example secp256k1 has G:(0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798, 0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8)
and n = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141
Number n is number points on curve, always <= prime?

Well, your algorithm for finite field multiplicative groups works for other finite groups since it doesn't use anything finite field specific and relies only on Lagrange theorem. You have the group operation (multiplication) used in power_mod(a, (p-1)//f,p) $\equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{f}}\mod p$ which in elliptic curve group is replaced with point addition (see e.g. https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/elliptic/explicit.html). So you would do in that notation $[\frac{p-1}{f}]a$ instead, where $a$ is the point.
Also, the group secp256k1 in question has order $n$ which is a prime and in a prime order group every element (besides the identity one) is a generator since according to the Lagrange theorem the order of an element has to divide the group order and with a prime group order you have only two choices.
